# RDFLib: Remove namespace from a URIRef resource

Tags: graph, ontology, rdflib

I have the following resource:
http://test.com/domainOnt/email#plans@plan.com

As in RDFLib, when you search for this in a graph, it returns a URIRef object. I would like to remove the namespace from the object so that it becomes plans@plan.com

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

URIRef objects in RDFLib are unicode objects and have all of the unicode object methods, like [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).  The following will work if all of your class names are separated from the namespace with a '#'.

```
resource = URIRef('http://test.com/domainOnt/email#plans@plan.com')
print resource.split('#')[-1]
```

This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830056/retrieving-the-class-name-of-a-specific-subclass-in-owl) is quite similar to yours.

Comment: The recipe is not so straightforward with non-hashed namespaces like [`rdflib.DCTERMS`](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/c50ee269c3a518e72931e476dd592ec5336b679a/rdflib/namespace.py#L287). 

Answer (score 1):

RDFLib classes have [this class hierarchy](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rdf_terms.html).

As you can see, a URIRef have the [`defrag` method, here defined](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.term.URIRef.defrag).

The part of the URL that you want to get is called 'fragment'. To get it, you can simply do the following:

```py
resource = URIRef('http://test.com/domainOnt/email#plans@plan.com')
result = resource.fragment
```

The example provided in RDFLib's documentation to return a URL fragment is the following:

```py
URIRef("http://example.com/some/path/#some-fragment").fragment
>> 'some-fragment'
URIRef("http://example.com/some/path/").fragment
>> ''
```