# retrieving the class name of a specific subclass in owl

Tags: python-2.7, sparql, owl, rdflib

I am an `rdflib` beginner, i have an ontology with classes and sub-classes and I need to look for a specific word in a subclass and, if it is found, return its class name.

I have the following code:

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import plugin
from rdflib.graph import Graph

g = Graph()
g.parse("test.owl")
from rdflib.namespace import Namespace
plugin.register(
  'sparql', rdflib.query.Processor,
  'rdfextras.sparql.processor', 'Processor')
plugin.register(
  'sparql', rdflib.query.Result,
  'rdfextras.sparql.query', 'SPARQLQueryResult')

qres = g.query("""
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
  PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

   SELECT  ?subject ?object
WHERE { ?subject rdfs:subClassOf ?object } 

  """)
# n is asubclass name and its class name is good-behaviour which i want to be the result
n="pity"
for (subj,pred,obj) in qres:
  if n in subj:
    print obj
  else:
    print "not found"
```

When I `print` the result of `qres` it returns a complete URL, and I need the name only of the sub-class and the class.

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: Things are identified by IRIs (which I expect is what you mean when you say URL) in RDF.  What is it that you're looking for?  Are you looking for the suffix of some IRI which has a defined prefix (e.g., `Foo` from `http://example.org/Foo` when `http://example.org/` has been defined as a prefix)?  Or are you looking for the value of some property such as `rdfs:label` (e.g., where the data contains `<http://example.org/Foo> rdfs:label "Foo"@en`)?

Comment: the result of my code is ('http://www.semanticweb.org/raya/ontologies/test6#Good-behaviour') and I need the result to be just 'Good- behaviour'

Comment: OK, so you just want the suffix of the string representation of the IRI.  That's not too hard;  I've added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RDFLib without SPARQL and Python string manipulation to get your answer.  If you prefer to use SPARQL, the Joshua Taylor [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845304/758157) would be the way to go.  You also don't need the SPARQL processor plugin with recent versions (4+) of RDFLib - see the ["Querying with SPARQL" documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro_to_sparql.html).

To get the answer you are looking for you can use the RDFLIB Graph method [subject_objects](https://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.graph.Graph) to get a generator of subjects and objects with the predicate you are interested in, rdfs:subClassOf.  Each subject and object will be an RDFLib URIRef, which are also Python unicode objects that can be manipulated using [standard Python methods](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html).  To get the suffix of the IRI call the [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of the object and take the last item in the returned list.

Here is your code reworked to do as described.  Without the data, I can't fully test it but this did work for me when using a different ontology.

```
from rdflib import Graph
from rdflib.namespace import RDFS

g = Graph()
g.parse("test.owl")

# n is a subclass name and its class name is good-behaviour
# which i want to be the result
n = "pity"

for subj, obj in g.subject_objects(predicate=RDFS.subClassOf):
    if n in subj:
        print obj.rsplit('#')[-1]
    else:
        print 'not found'
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your data, so I can't use your exact query or data, but based on your comments, it sounds like you're getting IRIs (e.g., `http://www.semanticweb.org/raya/ontologies/test6#Good-behaviour`) as results, and you want just the string `Good-behaviour`.  You can use [`strafter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strafter) to do that.  For instance, if you had data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830056/> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

:retrieving-the-class-name-of-a-specific-subclass-in-owl 
  rdfs:label "retrieving the class name of a specific subclass in owl"@en .
```

Then a query like this will return results that have full IRIs:

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?question where { 
  ?question rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| question                                                                                              |
=========================================================================================================
| <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830056/retrieving-the-class-name-of-a-specific-subclass-in-owl> |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can use `strafter` to get the part of a string after some other string.  E.g.,

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?q where { 
  ?question rdfs:label ?label .
  bind(strafter(str(?question),"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830056/") as ?q)
}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| q                                                         |
=============================================================
| "retrieving-the-class-name-of-a-specific-subclass-in-owl" |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you define the prefix in the query, e.g., as a `so:`, then you can also use `str(so:)` instead of the string form.  If you prefer, you can also do the string manipulation in the variable list rather than the graph pattern.   That would look like this:

```
prefix so: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830056/> 
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select (strafter(str(?question),str(so:)) as ?q) where { 
  ?question rdfs:label ?label .
}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| q                                                         |
=============================================================
| "retrieving-the-class-name-of-a-specific-subclass-in-owl" |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I edited the query to   'qres = g.query("""
     PREFIX so:<http://www.semanticweb.org/raya/ontologies/2013/11/untitled-ontology-6#>
     PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
     PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
     PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
     PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
     SELECT DISTINCT  (strafter(str(?varsubClass),str(so:))  as ?subj) 
     WHERE {
       
       ?varSubClass rdfs:subClassOf ?varClass
       
       }""")'

Comment: and it gives me the following error'File "hope.py", line 26, in <module>
    }""")         File "graph.py", line 1045, in query query_object, initBindings, initNs, **kwargs)) strOrQuery = rdfextras.sparql.parser.parse(strOrQuery) File "parser.py", line 794, in parse return Query.parseString(stuff)[0] File "pyparsing.py", line 1006, in parseString raise exc ParseException: Expected "?" )'

Comment: There shouldn't be semicolons between the prefixes.

Comment: @MonyT It's next to impossible to read code in the comments;  please edit the question and post it there.  That said, you have semicolons between your prefix declarations, and those certainly shouldn't be there.  sparql.org has a [query validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) that you can use to check whether your query is well formed.

Comment: thanks joshua, I think the other way mentioned by lawlesst is much easier as sparql is not my Specialty.