# Changing the format of results obtained from an ontology

Tags: rdf, sparql

I am running a SPARQL Query against an ontology and getting the results. But, the complete URIs are displayed in the results.

For Example:

SPARQL Query

```
SELECT ?s where { ?s :wasBornIn :Ulm } LIMIT 1
```

Result -

```
s={http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Albert_Einstein}
```

Instead of the complete URI, I want only "Albert_Einstein" to be printed. Is there any way to accomplish this without using the *rdfs:label* property and *Model.SetNsPrefix(String nsprefix, String URI)* method.

Comment: See [Exclude results from DBpedia SPARQL query based on URI prefix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19044871/1281433).  It doesn't exactly answer this question, but it demonstrates some of the functions that AndyS mentions that you'll need.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20845304/1281433, which *does* show how to do what you're trying to do using `strafter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it:

1. If you are using Jena Java code to make the query, ask for the resources "local name"
2. In SPARQL, there many ways, depending on how general you want to be, using `BIND` or a SELECT expression (e.g. `(STRAFTER(....) AS ?sName))`

   `STRAFTER(str(?s), "http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/")`

   `REPLACE(str(?s), "(.*)/", "")`

See the spec for details of each function.