# Pull string from RDF node

Tags: java, sparql, jena, owl, ontology

Im trying to get the data in a more readable format when using a SPARQL query with Jena, however I have no idea how to extract the data in a proper way.
As for now, the output is:

"http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#SaucelitoCanyon"

Where instead would like to just have the "SaucelitoCanyon" as a output.

```
public JenaQuery() {

    String wineRegion = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\n"
            + "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\n"
            + "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"
            + "PREFIX wine:<http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#>\n"
            + "SELECT  ?region ?winery \n"
            + "WHERE {?wine wine:locatedIn ?region . \n"
            + "?region wine:locatedIn wine:CaliforniaRegion  . \n"
            + "?wine wine:hasMaker  ?winery}";

    String inputFileName = "wine.rdf";
    // create an empty model

    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    // use the FileManager to find the input file
    InputStream in;
    in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }
    // read the RDF/XML file
    model.read(in, null);
    try (QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(wineRegion, model)) {

        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();

        while (results.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution row = results.next();
            RDFNode winery = row.get("winery");
            System.out.println(winery);
        }

        qexec.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: You can do this all in the SPARQL query, as described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20845304/1281433) to [retrieving the class name of a specific subclass in owl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20830056/1281433).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ["getLocalName" function](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Resource.html#getLocalName()) in Jena. That will get you the local name of the resource, which is what you seem to be looking for:

```
QuerySolution row = results.next();
RDFNode winery = row.get("winery");
String r = winery.asNode().getLocalName();
System.out.println(r);
```

Alternatively you can get the node as a resource directly, which saves you one line of code:

```
String r = row.getResource("winery").getLocalName();
```

Edit: as stated in the comments below, this answer will only be valid if your prefix "wine" is as you have declared it in your code. Otherwise the results may not be as desired.

Comment: A given URI can be broken down into any number of prefixes and localnames.  E.g., you could split `http://example.org/foobar` as ex:foobar, ex1:oobar, ex2:obar, ex3:bar, ex4:ar, ex5:r, given appropriate declarations of ex, ex1, ex2, etc.  Jena's getLocalName applies a heuristic, but isn't guaranteed to give one that's based on the prefix declaration from the original file.  Since this is using a SPARQL, query where there's a prefix in the query, it might make more sense just to use that prefix and split the string in the query.

Comment: That is true. I was assuming the prefix he had in his code. I will update my answer reflecting your comment. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Since you've already got the prefix in the SPARQL query, you can use the **strafter** and **str** functions to convert the URIs to strings and take the suffix after the prefix.  In the following, I've used `values ?winery { ... }` to bind `?winery` to a particular URI, but your query already takes care of that.  The important part is the **bind** afterward that takes care of the string processing.

```sql
PREFIX wine: <http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#>
SELECT ?winery ?localname
WHERE {
  values ?winery { wine:SomeWinery }
  bind( strafter(str(?winery),str(wine:)) as ?localname )
}
```

```
winery                                                            localname
<http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#SomeWinery> "SomeWinery"
```

That said, in well structured ontologies, individuals will often have an **rdfs:label** that should provide a string label for an individual.  When it's available, you might consider simply retrieving that value.  E.g.,

```sql
SELECT ?winery ?name
WHERE {
  #-- ... 
  ?winery rdfs:label ?name
}
```

This was previously described in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20845304/1281433) to [retrieving the class name of a specific subclass in owl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20830056/1281433), but that question didn't involve Jena, so it's not quite a duplicate, even though the same SPARQL-based solution works.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out. I just encountered something strange which I cant explain. When changing the region from CaliforniaRegion to any other region I dont get any results from the queries. I dont really understand since I can see other regions in the Wine ontology. I've also just started with SPARQL and Jena so i'm having a real difficult time understanding what and if im doing it correct.

Comment: str(wine:) : nice one, I did not know it was possible to use prefixes inside sparql string functions

Comment: @thomas it's not the prefix, per se, but the IRI. You could use wine:foo; this is just using the IRI from the prefix and no suffix.

Answer (score 5):

Note that in Jena you have two nice Java sources for nice qName conversions: `Prologue` and `PrefixMapping`. Your `Model` is a `PrefixMapping` and your `Query` (if you compiled it) is a `Prologue`. Both of these objects have a `#shortForm(String uri)` method that you can use to get a shortened form of a URI without modifying your query.

If your model has prefixes defined in it, you can use [`PrefixMapping#shortForm(String)`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/shared/PrefixMapping.html#shortForm%28java.lang.String%29) as follows (pseudocode):

```java
final Model m = // TODO
final String shortForm = m.shortForm(winery.asResource().getURI());
```

If you compile your `Query` using `QueryFactory`, then you can use query-specific prefixes in [`Prologue#shortForm(String)`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/sparql/core/Prologue.html#shortForm%28java.lang.String%29) as follows (pseudocode):

```
final Query q = QueryFactory.create(/* TODO */);   
final String shortForm = q.shortForm(winery.asResource().getURI());
```

It's then worth knowing that this will give you a name of the form `wine:SaucelitoCanyon` (if the `wine:` prefix is defined, otherwise it will give you `http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#SaucelitoCanyon`). You would still need to split the resulting string to get just the local name which may be a little verbose:

```
final String longName = winery.asResource().getURI();
final String localName;
if(  !shortForm.equals(longName) ) {
    localName = shortForm.split(":")[1];
}
else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("could not resolve prefix for "+longName);
}
```

This provides you a guarantee that you are using the local name associated with some prefix in your model or your query.